# iOS - NSNotifiction invalid selector

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I'm having some trouble understanding why this is happening but for some reason when the NSNotification gets triggered for the second time this happens:

```
-[UITableViewCel lContentView imageFound:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd837e0 2013-08-12 16:32:24.340 poundtaxi[7483:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView imageFound:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd837e0'
```

*** First throw call stack: (0x344d92a3 0x3c17e97f 0x344dce07 0x344db531 0x34432f68 0x3442a037 0x34d40599 0xd7d9f 0x33d64145 0x3c59611f 0x3c5954b7 0x3c596dcb 0x344acf3b 0x3441febd 0x3441fd49 0x37fe32eb 0x36335301 0xb963d 0x3c5b5b20) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Here is the block of code that gets executed:

```
-(void)imageFound:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
    Picture *aPicture = (Picture *) [userInfo objectForKey:@"picture"];
    UIImage *image = (UIImage *) [userInfo objectForKey:@"image"];

    aPicture.highResPicture = image;
    self.count++;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that a registered observer object was released before being removed as an observer. Always remember to remove notification center observers in dealloc.